# How to set InternetExplorerOptions in Jmeter WebDriver Sampler using JavaScript language?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, webdriver

I am new to Jmeter and selenium web driver.

I need some help to set the following options using JavaScript language in Webdriver Sampler.

```
    InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions() options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true options.EnableNativeEvents = false 
    options.EnsureCleanSession = true
```

This is the template code that it has after adding Weddriver Sampler:

```
    WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
    WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
    WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Can someone please help me with the code sample on how to set it using JavaScript from loading the package and setting the options and incorporating into the template code above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below snippet:-

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium);

pkg.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
pkg.EnableNativeEvents = false; 
pkg.EnsureCleanSession = true;

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per [WebDriver Sampler 3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/3.1) it is not possible, the initialization is happening inside [InternetExplorerDriverConfig.java](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/config/InternetExplorerDriverConfig.java#L31) class so you will either have to amend this class to include your changes, recompile the .jar and replace the one in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

or you can write your Selenium-related code using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/), this way you will have full control over the WebDriver instance, but you will have to care about kicking off and shutting down the browser instance(s)